# Why is array.length returning me wrong number?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

This is my javascript code in which I am calling a php file each 5 seconds ,the php file returns some id's in form of javascript array but array.length is giving me 18 while there are only 2 elements in the array.

PHP file response:

```
["20","1"]
```

```js
//function to rotate thumbnails
  window.setInterval(function () {    
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var index;
                var a = xmlhttp.responseText;
                for (index = 0; index < a.length; index++) {
                    pass_value_to_other_function(a[index]);
                }               
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "thumb_rotator.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: your console.log for 'a' confirms what you claim?

Comment: The response is **string**, to convert it to JSON, use `JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: I got it , thanks it works after parsing it

Comment: Maybe mark the first answer as Accepted (it's correct after all)

Comment: @BrainyPrb Welcome! Glad to help.

Comment: I bet you are not ussing `Array.length` at all. You must be calling `String.length`.

Comment: @ChrisLear yes waiting for 2 more minutes to pass so that I can accept the answer as per stackoverflow norms (can accept answer after 5 mins of posting ) :)

Comment: @AlanMachado but for ["20","1"] as response string why is it echoing 18 , as I see 10 is the length of this string.

Comment: Sorry, @BrainyPrb. I was being over-hasty. My mistake.

Comment: @BrainyPrb Did you count white space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to parse the response to a javascript Object/Array.

```
var a = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```